# Usage of varnish cache at the database record level

Tags: varnish

I'm working with a legacy codebase for a web app with an architecture that they call "widget based". It's basically cached database result sets of data that is to be presented on several "widgets" in different parts of the application.  So, when they update or create a new record, they use a set of rules to know which caches to invalidate so that said record would be presented.

By reading the varnish use case examples, it looks like it's not built to cache database records (like memcache or apc), but a **webserver's response itself** (AKA, the whole html page).

If my last statement is correct, how can I invalidate only the varnish cache's cache registries for the html pages that shows the new record (basically, cherry-picking what to invalidate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purge the contents of the cache. This is explained in this section of the documentation [Purging and Banning](http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/purging.html)

Basicly you added something like this in the VCL file

```
acl purge {
        "localhost";
        "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
        # allow PURGE from localhost and 192.168.55...

        if (req.method == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
                }
                return (purge);
        }
}
```

And after restarting the server you can purge pages using the method PURGE.

For example, if you have the following url: http://yourhost.com/widget/a ,
you send a purge request to the same address to remove it from the cache.

You can use the command line utility curl for that as below, but any tool / library that allow to send custom HTTP methods will work:

```
curl -X PURGE http://yourhost.com/widget/a
```